# Simple Form Select without Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am using Simple Forms (w/ Rails 3.2) and would like to create a form with a select.

For example:

```
Email Format :Text and HTML
             :Text Only
             :HTML Only
```

I do not want to create a model with associations for such a simple select. How do I add this to the form without a model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
f.input :email_format, :collection => ["Text and HTML", "Text Only", "HTML Only"], :prompt => "select email format"
```

Refer [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form#collections)

Comment: Does not work for me in Rails 4.1. undefined method `email_format'. Seems to need a value to work.  As a simple text input (f.input :email_format, input_html: {value: "Text and HTML"}).  As a select you need:     = f.input :email_format, collection: ["Text and HTML", "Text Only", "HTML Only"],  selected: "Text Only",:prompt => "select email format" to provide the value to avoid the method name call.

Answer (score 0):

`<%= f.input :format, collection: ["Text and HTML", "Text only", "HTML only"] %>`
Should work, though, if you're not going to store it in any model I'm not sure what the point is. I would add it your e-mail model as a string.